# change the sequence of numbers in a filename using R

Tags: r, csv

I am sorry, I could not find an answer to this question anywhere and would really appreciate your help.

I have .csv files for each hour of a year. The filename is written in the following way:
hh_dd_mm.csv (e.g. for February 1st 00:00--> 00_01_02.csv). In order to make it easier to sort the hours of a year I would like to change the filename to mm_dd_hh.csv

How can I write in R to change the filename from the pattern HH_DD_MM to MM_DD_HH?

```
a <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "HH_DD_MM") 
b<-paste(pattern="MM_DD_HH")
file.rename(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do:

```
a <- c("00_01_02.csv",  "00_02_02.csv")
gsub("(\\d{2})\\_(\\d{2})\\_(\\d{2})(.*)", "\\3_\\2_\\1\\4", a)
#[1] "02_01_00.csv" "02_02_00.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but seem to work

```
a <- c("00_01_02.csv",  "00_02_02.csv")
b <- unname(sapply(a, function(x) {temp <- strsplit(x, "(_|[.])")[[1]] ; paste0(temp[[3]], "_", temp[[2]], "_", temp[[1]], ".", temp[[4]])}))
b
## [1] "02_01_00.csv" "02_02_00.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `chartr` to create the new file name. Here's an example..

```
> write.csv(c(1,1), "12_34_56")
> list.files()
# [1] "12_34_56"
> file.rename("12_34_56", chartr("1256", "5612", "12_34_56"))
# [1] TRUE
> list.files()
# [1] "56_34_12"
```

In `chartr`, you can replace the elements of a string, so long as it doesn't change the number of characters in the original string.  In the above code, I basically just swapped `"12"` with `"56"`, which is what it looks like you are trying to do.

Or, you can write a short string swapping function

```
> strSwap <- function(x) paste(rev(strsplit(x, "[_]")[[1]]), collapse = "_")
> ( files <- c("84_15_45", "59_95_21", "31_51_49",   
               "51_88_27", "21_39_98", "35_27_14") )
# [1] "84_15_45" "59_95_21" "31_51_49" "51_88_27" "21_39_98" "35_27_14"
> sapply(files, strSwap, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
# [1] "45_15_84" "21_95_59" "49_51_31" "27_88_51" "98_39_21" "14_27_35"
```

You could also so it with the `substr<-` assignment function

```
> s1 <- substr(files,1,2)
> substr(files,1,2) <- substr(files,7,8)
> substr(files,7,8) <- s1
> files
# [1] "45_15_84" "21_95_59" "49_51_31" "27_88_51" "98_39_21" "14_27_35"
```